# How to write a function which accepts a slice of interfaces and returns a slice of concrete structs?

Tags: go, interface, composition

I am currently trying to create a package which comprises of functions which accept interfaces (`Flyer`) and return concrete models (`Bird`).

I have an interface, which describes a bird which can fly:

```
type Flyer interface {
    Fly() string
}
```

I have a concrete type called `Duck`, which implements the method `Fly()` (satisfying the `Flyer` interface).

```
type Duck struct{}

func (d *Duck) Fly() string {
    return "Duck starts flying"
}
```

I want to write a function which accepts a slice of any struct which implements the `Flyer` interface and return a concretion of the `Bird` struct.

```
func NewFlock(f []Flyer) []*Bird {
    result := []*Bird{}
    for _, v := range f {
        isFlying := v.Fly() != ""
        result = append(result, &Bird{
            IsFlying: isFlying,
        })
    }

    return result
}
```

However, this results in:

```
./prog.go:38:23: cannot use ducks (variable of type []*Duck) as type []Flyer in argument to NewFlock
```

Now from my understanding, Duck implements all the methods in order to satisfy the Flyer interface, so why does this result in a compile error?

If this is not possible, how can I abide by the advice:

> accept interfaces, return concretions

when it comes to slices of structs?

Full code: https://go.dev/play/p/ThsHX7loGlu

Answer (score 3):

> so why does this result in a compile error?

`[]Flyer` is not an interface type, it is a concrete type, to be able to assign to a concrete type the value being assigned must either have an identical type or the two types need to have identical underlying type and one of them must be unnamed, and there are other rules as well, see: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability

Use generics if you want the code to compile: https://go.dev/play/p/Ygu7dlvgYVf

Comment: Fantastic thanks for the help! 

Lets say I needed `f []Flyer` to be provided by a method on a larger struct (which implements another interface)? 

I have tried this and I get: `InvalidInterfaceAssign`.

Is this possible with go?

Full code: https://go.dev/play/p/hgyd4PyjDIB

Comment: Something like this: https://go.dev/play/p/6j-gJcVzKlg

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And what happens if that `Releaser` needs to have multiple methods both returning slices of structs which implement interfaces? Is that possible!

Comment: Ignore me! I would just do `[T1 TypeOne, T2, TypeTwo] `